# Java to validate csv file with incomplete rows

Tags: java, file, java-io

Our java application reads csv files into memory, but before we read the file, we would like to validate the csv file and throw error if the file contains incomplete rows (i.e. last row's columns are incomplete)

Comment: You have to read the file to validate it.

Comment: why not validate as you read?

Comment: I can. any recommended way of checking incomplete rows?

Comment: you need some csv reader to proper checking. I recomment apache commons-csv library.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 2):

CSV fields are separated by ';' or ',' . Simply read the file, split lines using this character and count expected field number

```
String SEPARATOR = ";";
int EXPECTED = 4;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    String fields[] = line.split(SEPARATOR);
    if (fields.length != EXPECTED){
        //doSomething with the error
    } else {
        //line ok. Process it
    }   
}
```

Comment: Csv can have multi-line values if escaped correctly, I would advise to use some CSV lib

Comment: @enfany note that ';'  may also appear as a value in a field like "abcd; efg". This code is a simple example